# Using ArcGIS API for Python and Windows Authentication?

Tags: authentication, arcgis-python-api, attributeerror

I've been trying to follow the [ESRI recommended workflow](https://developers.arcgis.com/python/guide/working-with-different-authentication-schemes/)  to log on to Enterprise (using authentication), but it just doesn't want to work. I'm able to get the account credentials registered in Windows Credential Manager, but if I try to run the program and access them via the API for Python, I keep receiving this error:

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)

<ipython-input-1-9fd4325b765b> in <module>

     11

     12

---> 13 gis =GIS(portal_url,profile=portal_profile, verify_cert=portal_cert_check)

     14 print('Good')

 

~\AppData\Local\ESRI\conda\envs\arcgispro-py3-clone1\lib\site-packages\arcgis\gis\__init__.py in __init__(self, url, username, password, key_file, cert_file, verify_cert, set_active, client_id, profile, **kwargs)

    337                                    "argument when connecting to the GIS.")

    338             else:

--> 339                 raise e

    340         try:

    341             if url.lower().find("arcgis.com") > -1 and \

 

~\AppData\Local\ESRI\conda\envs\arcgispro-py3-clone1\lib\site-packages\arcgis\gis\__init__.py in __init__(self, url, username, password, key_file, cert_file, verify_cert, set_active, client_id, profile, **kwargs)

    321                                            expiration=self._expiration,

    322                                            referer=self._referer,

--> 323                                            custom_auth=custom_auth)

    324             if self._is_hosted_nb_home:

    325                 # For GIS("home") objects, force no referer passed in

 

~\AppData\Local\ESRI\conda\envs\arcgispro-py3-clone1\lib\site-packages\arcgis\gis\_impl\_portalpy.py in __init__(self, url, username, password, key_file, cert_file, expiration, referer, proxy_host, proxy_port, connection, workdir, tokenurl, verify_cert, client_id, custom_auth, token)

    165                                       client_id=client_id,

    166                                       custom_auth=custom_auth,

--> 167                                       token=token)

    168         #self.get_version(True)

    169         self.get_properties(True)

 

~\AppData\Local\ESRI\conda\envs\arcgispro-py3-clone1\lib\site-packages\arcgis\gis\_impl\_con\_connection.py in __init__(self, baseurl, username, password, **kwargs)

    156             self._auth = "PKI"

    157

--> 158         self._create_session()

    159

    160         #  Product Info

 

~\AppData\Local\ESRI\conda\envs\arcgispro-py3-clone1\lib\site-packages\arcgis\gis\_impl\_con\_connection.py in _create_session(self)

    260             self._session.auth = GuessAuth(username=self._username,

    261                                            password=self._password)

--> 262         elif self._auth.lower() == "pro":

    263             self._session.auth = GuessAuth(None, None)

    264         else:

 

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'lower'
```

Comment: You trimmed the code too tightly.  The whole `if` statement (at least) is needed to expose the bug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe check the details in this bug

https://support.esri.com/en/bugs/nimbus/QlVHLTAwMDEwODA2Mw==

This bug is affecting me. and there doesn't seem to be a work around. its possibly related to the Python version, thats my next step is to downgrade.

FYI im using ArcGIS API 1.4.1 and Python 3.8